# Converting from httpclient 3 to httpclient 4 (Cookie policy)

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Previously, I have the following code in httpclient3

```
// To prevent cookie warnings.
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.single-cookie-header", true);
httpClient.getParams().setCookiePolicy(org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

I was wondering, what is the equivalent code in httpclient4, as I am getting error in the 2nd line.

```
// To prevent cookie warnings.
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.single-cookie-header", true);
// ??? compilation error in this line.
// org.apache.commons.httpclient cannot be resolved to a variable
httpClient.getParams().setCookiePolicy(org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

Comment: updated with error information.

Comment: It seems you have case issue issue. httpclient should be httpClient.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK Did either the above or my answer fix the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link may aid you in resolving your issue.

http://www.wirelust.com/2009/03/29/howto-set-the-cookie-policy-with-apache-http-client-40/

So try this line:

```
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the version 4.3 `getParams()`, `ClientPNames` and `CookiePolicy` are all deprecated. In order to achieve the same result you'd have to do:

```
final RequestConfig params = RequestConfig
        .custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES)
        .build();

httpPost.setConfig(params);
```